# Weird artifacts after sculpting with multires

Tags: sculpting

[image: Screenshot]

So these strange artifacts appear, as soon as i smooth them out they appear again. I think it's after i added some loopcuts, idk how to fix it.
I tried to apply "apply base" but it doesn't work.